# Split html page: half code, half image

Tags: html, wordpress

Before to ask my question, take a look at this: http://db.tt/IdmsYZYS
I have some trouble with let black image touch the bottom, the top and the right side of the text box. So that in fact the black image will cover the whole right part of the spitted box.

I am using Wordpress. Maybe you have some tips for me. But just HTML code is also great.

Thansk a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an element to have 100% height within a container that has a fluid height. You should try using the [Faux Column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique, which solves your problem.